# Python Adding sub-child elements throughout XML using BS4

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, element

Using a large XML file, Python and BS4 I want to add sub child elements throughout. 
I want to add 3 elements called DB-RU, LAD-RU and LAW-RU inside each individual `<Learner>` tag. 
These fields can be filled with a string of "Null" 
Using the mock XML data below

I have tried using Element Tree yet found it added multiple problems. 1 being it added `</ns0:>` to all the element names. So would like to use BS4 if possible

Below is the XML Mock Data for 2 learners (Yet it will have to run through for possibly hundreds of learners.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Please note that this file is properly formed, and serves as an example of a file that will load into the ILR DC system.  The data is anonymised and does not refer to a real-world provider, learning delivery or learner.  Based on the ILR specification, version 2, dated April 2018-->
<Message xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="ESFA/ILR/2018-19" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="ESFA/ILR/2018-19">
    <Header>
        <CollectionDetails>
            <Collection>ILR</Collection>
            <Year>1819</Year>
            <FilePreparationDate>2018-01-07</FilePreparationDate>
        </CollectionDetails>
        <Source>
            <ProtectiveMarking>OFFICIAL-SENSITIVE-Personal</ProtectiveMarking>
            <UKPRN>99999999</UKPRN>
            <SoftwareSupplier>SupplierName</SoftwareSupplier>
            <SoftwarePackage>SystemName</SoftwarePackage>
            <Release>1</Release>
            <SerialNo>01</SerialNo>
            <DateTime>2018-06-26T11:14:05</DateTime>
            <!-- This and the next element only appear in files generated by FIS -->
            <ReferenceData>Version5.0, LARS 2017-08-01</ReferenceData>
            <ComponentSetVersion>1</ComponentSetVersion>
        </Source>
    </Header>
    <SourceFiles>
        <!-- The SourceFiles group only appears in files generated by FIS -->
        <SourceFile>
            <SourceFileName>ILR-LLLLLLLL1819-20180626-144401-01.xml</SourceFileName>
            <FilePreparationDate>2018-06-26</FilePreparationDate>
            <SoftwareSupplier>Software Systems Inc.</SoftwareSupplier>
            <SoftwarePackage>GreatStuffMIS</SoftwarePackage>
            <Release>1</Release>
            <SerialNo>01</SerialNo>
            <DateTime>2018-06-26T11:14:05</DateTime>
        </SourceFile>
    </SourceFiles>
    <LearningProvider>
        <UKPRN>99999999</UKPRN>
    </LearningProvider>
    <!-- 16 yr old learner undertaking full time 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded programme -->
    <Learner>
        <LearnRefNumber>16Learner</LearnRefNumber>
        <PMUKPRN>87654321</PMUKPRN>
        <CampId>1234ABCD</CampId>
        <ULN>1061484016</ULN>
        <FamilyName>Smith</FamilyName>
        <GivenNames>Jane</GivenNames>
        <DateOfBirth>1999-02-27</DateOfBirth>
        <Ethnicity>31</Ethnicity>
        <Sex>F</Sex>
        <LLDDHealthProb>2</LLDDHealthProb>
        <Accom>5</Accom>
        <PlanLearnHours>440</PlanLearnHours>
        <PlanEEPHours>100</PlanEEPHours>
        <MathGrade>NONE</MathGrade>
        <EngGrade>D</EngGrade>
        <PostcodePrior>BR1 7SS</PostcodePrior>
        <Postcode>BR1 7SS</Postcode>
        <AddLine1>The Street</AddLine1>
        <AddLine2>ToyTown</AddLine2>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>LSR</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>55</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>EDF</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>MCF</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>3</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>FME</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>PPE</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <!-- Employment status record is not required for full time 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded learners  -->
        <!-- 16-19  (excluding apprenticeships) funded study programme -->
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50022246</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>5</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>1</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-09-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR1 3RL</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>1</CompStatus>
            <SWSupAimId>cb5f0d25-cff4-4ea0-92f5-99378cce306d</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50023408</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>4</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>2</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-02-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-15</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR2 7UP</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>3</CompStatus>
            <LearnActEndDate>2015-04-01</LearnActEndDate>
            <WithdrawReason>98</WithdrawReason>
            <Outcome>3</Outcome>
            <SWSupAimId>c243182a-30af-4879-8f68-3eac708e6bb3</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
    </Learner>
    <!-- 18 yr old learner undertaking a part-time 16-19  (excluding apprenticeships) funded programme -->
    <Learner>
        <LearnRefNumber>18Learner</LearnRefNumber>
        <CampId>1234ABCD</CampId>
        <ULN>1061484466</ULN>
        <FamilyName>Smith</FamilyName>
        <GivenNames>Jane</GivenNames>
        <DateOfBirth>1997-02-27</DateOfBirth>
        <Ethnicity>31</Ethnicity>
        <Sex>F</Sex>
        <LLDDHealthProb>2</LLDDHealthProb>
        <Accom>5</Accom>
        <ALSCost>19000</ALSCost>
        <PlanLearnHours>340</PlanLearnHours>
        <PlanEEPHours>5</PlanEEPHours>
        <MathGrade>C</MathGrade>
        <EngGrade>C</EngGrade>
        <PostcodePrior>BR1 7SS</PostcodePrior>
        <Postcode>BR1 7SS</Postcode>
        <AddLine1>The Street</AddLine1>
        <AddLine2>ToyTown</AddLine2>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>HNS</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>1</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>EHC</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>1</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>LSR</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>55</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <!--  Employment status record required for part-time 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded learning  -->
        <LearnerEmploymentStatus>
            <EmpStat>10</EmpStat>
            <DateEmpStatApp>2015-05-13</DateEmpStatApp>
            <EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
                <ESMType>EII</ESMType>
                <ESMCode>3</ESMCode>
            </EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
        </LearnerEmploymentStatus>
        <!-- 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded study programme -->
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50023494</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>4</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>1</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-05-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-09-30</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR2 7UP</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>1</CompStatus>
            <SWSupAimId>baf7117c-2417-4ee2-8772-4136f2fac383</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50022246</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>5</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>2</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-09-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR1 3RL</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>1</CompStatus>
            <SWSupAimId>3213a395-9457-4f2b-9d86-20af2363ca02</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
    </Learner>
```

At the bottom of each learner tag I have highlighted with ** tags what I expect to output to produce.

```
<Learner>
        <LearnRefNumber>16Learner</LearnRefNumber>
        <PMUKPRN>87654321</PMUKPRN>
        <CampId>1234ABCD</CampId>
        <ULN>1061484016</ULN>
        <FamilyName>Smith</FamilyName>
        <GivenNames>Jane</GivenNames>
        <DateOfBirth>1999-02-27</DateOfBirth>
        <Ethnicity>31</Ethnicity>
        <Sex>F</Sex>
        <LLDDHealthProb>2</LLDDHealthProb>
        <Accom>5</Accom>
        <PlanLearnHours>440</PlanLearnHours>
        <PlanEEPHours>100</PlanEEPHours>
        <MathGrade>NONE</MathGrade>
        <EngGrade>D</EngGrade>
        <PostcodePrior>BR1 7SS</PostcodePrior>
        <Postcode>BR1 7SS</Postcode>
        <AddLine1>The Street</AddLine1>
        <AddLine2>ToyTown</AddLine2>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>LSR</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>55</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>EDF</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>MCF</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>3</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>FME</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>PPE</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <!-- Employment status record is not required for full time 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded learners  -->
        <!-- 16-19  (excluding apprenticeships) funded study programme -->
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50022246</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>5</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>1</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-09-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR1 3RL</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>1</CompStatus>
            <SWSupAimId>cb5f0d25-cff4-4ea0-92f5-99378cce306d</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50023408</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>4</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>2</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-02-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-15</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR2 7UP</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>3</CompStatus>
            <LearnActEndDate>2015-04-01</LearnActEndDate>
            <WithdrawReason>98</WithdrawReason>
            <Outcome>3</Outcome>
            <SWSupAimId>c243182a-30af-4879-8f68-3eac708e6bb3</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
                **<DB-RU> NULL </DB-RU>**
                **<LAD-RU> NULL </LAD-RU>**
                **<LAW-RU> NULL </LAW-RU>** 
    </Learner>
    <!-- 18 yr old learner undertaking a part-time 16-19  (excluding apprenticeships) funded programme -->
    <Learner>
        <LearnRefNumber>18Learner</LearnRefNumber>
        <CampId>1234ABCD</CampId>
        <ULN>1061484466</ULN>
        <FamilyName>Smith</FamilyName>
        <GivenNames>Jane</GivenNames>
        <DateOfBirth>1997-02-27</DateOfBirth>
        <Ethnicity>31</Ethnicity>
        <Sex>F</Sex>
        <LLDDHealthProb>2</LLDDHealthProb>
        <Accom>5</Accom>
        <ALSCost>19000</ALSCost>
        <PlanLearnHours>340</PlanLearnHours>
        <PlanEEPHours>5</PlanEEPHours>
        <MathGrade>C</MathGrade>
        <EngGrade>C</EngGrade>
        <PostcodePrior>BR1 7SS</PostcodePrior>
        <Postcode>BR1 7SS</Postcode>
        <AddLine1>The Street</AddLine1>
        <AddLine2>ToyTown</AddLine2>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>HNS</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>1</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>EHC</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>1</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>LSR</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>55</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <!--  Employment status record required for part-time 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded learning  -->
        <LearnerEmploymentStatus>
            <EmpStat>10</EmpStat>
            <DateEmpStatApp>2015-05-13</DateEmpStatApp>
            <EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
                <ESMType>EII</ESMType>
                <ESMCode>3</ESMCode>
            </EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
        </LearnerEmploymentStatus>
        <!-- 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded study programme -->
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50023494</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>4</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>1</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-05-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-09-30</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR2 7UP</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>1</CompStatus>
            <SWSupAimId>baf7117c-2417-4ee2-8772-4136f2fac383</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50022246</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>5</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>2</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-09-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR1 3RL</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>1</CompStatus>
            <SWSupAimId>3213a395-9457-4f2b-9d86-20af2363ca02</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
                **<DB-RU> NULL </DB-RU>**
                **<LAD-RU> NULL </LAD-RU>**
                **<LAW-RU> NULL </LAW-RU>** 


    </Learner>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are looking after this. First you need to find the element you want to insert tag after.Here is the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<Learner>
        <LearnRefNumber>16Learner</LearnRefNumber>
        <PMUKPRN>87654321</PMUKPRN>
        <CampId>1234ABCD</CampId>
        <ULN>1061484016</ULN>
        <FamilyName>Smith</FamilyName>
        <GivenNames>Jane</GivenNames>
        <DateOfBirth>1999-02-27</DateOfBirth>
        <Ethnicity>31</Ethnicity>
        <Sex>F</Sex>
        <LLDDHealthProb>2</LLDDHealthProb>
        <Accom>5</Accom>
        <PlanLearnHours>440</PlanLearnHours>
        <PlanEEPHours>100</PlanEEPHours>
        <MathGrade>NONE</MathGrade>
        <EngGrade>D</EngGrade>
        <PostcodePrior>BR1 7SS</PostcodePrior>
        <Postcode>BR1 7SS</Postcode>
        <AddLine1>The Street</AddLine1>
        <AddLine2>ToyTown</AddLine2>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>LSR</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>55</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>EDF</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>MCF</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>3</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>FME</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>PPE</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>2</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <!-- Employment status record is not required for full time 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded learners  -->
        <!-- 16-19  (excluding apprenticeships) funded study programme -->
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50022246</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>5</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>1</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-09-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR1 3RL</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>1</CompStatus>
            <SWSupAimId>cb5f0d25-cff4-4ea0-92f5-99378cce306d</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50023408</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>4</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>2</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-02-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-15</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR2 7UP</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>3</CompStatus>
            <LearnActEndDate>2015-04-01</LearnActEndDate>
            <WithdrawReason>98</WithdrawReason>
            <Outcome>3</Outcome>
            <SWSupAimId>c243182a-30af-4879-8f68-3eac708e6bb3</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>

    </Learner>
    <!-- 18 yr old learner undertaking a part-time 16-19  (excluding apprenticeships) funded programme -->
    <Learner>
        <LearnRefNumber>18Learner</LearnRefNumber>
        <CampId>1234ABCD</CampId>
        <ULN>1061484466</ULN>
        <FamilyName>Smith</FamilyName>
        <GivenNames>Jane</GivenNames>
        <DateOfBirth>1997-02-27</DateOfBirth>
        <Ethnicity>31</Ethnicity>
        <Sex>F</Sex>
        <LLDDHealthProb>2</LLDDHealthProb>
        <Accom>5</Accom>
        <ALSCost>19000</ALSCost>
        <PlanLearnHours>340</PlanLearnHours>
        <PlanEEPHours>5</PlanEEPHours>
        <MathGrade>C</MathGrade>
        <EngGrade>C</EngGrade>
        <PostcodePrior>BR1 7SS</PostcodePrior>
        <Postcode>BR1 7SS</Postcode>
        <AddLine1>The Street</AddLine1>
        <AddLine2>ToyTown</AddLine2>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>HNS</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>1</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>EHC</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>1</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <LearnerFAM>
            <LearnFAMType>LSR</LearnFAMType>
            <LearnFAMCode>55</LearnFAMCode>
        </LearnerFAM>
        <!--  Employment status record required for part-time 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded learning  -->
        <LearnerEmploymentStatus>
            <EmpStat>10</EmpStat>
            <DateEmpStatApp>2015-05-13</DateEmpStatApp>
            <EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
                <ESMType>EII</ESMType>
                <ESMCode>3</ESMCode>
            </EmploymentStatusMonitoring>
        </LearnerEmploymentStatus>
        <!-- 16-19 (excluding apprenticeships) funded study programme -->
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50023494</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>4</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>1</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-05-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-09-30</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR2 7UP</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>1</CompStatus>
            <SWSupAimId>baf7117c-2417-4ee2-8772-4136f2fac383</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>
        <LearningDelivery>
            <LearnAimRef>50022246</LearnAimRef>
            <AimType>5</AimType>
            <AimSeqNumber>2</AimSeqNumber>
            <LearnStartDate>2015-09-14</LearnStartDate>
            <LearnPlanEndDate>2016-07-02</LearnPlanEndDate>
            <FundModel>25</FundModel>
            <DelLocPostCode>BR1 3RL</DelLocPostCode>
            <CompStatus>1</CompStatus>
            <SWSupAimId>3213a395-9457-4f2b-9d86-20af2363ca02</SWSupAimId>
            <LearningDeliveryFAM>
                <LearnDelFAMType>SOF</LearnDelFAMType>
                <LearnDelFAMCode>107</LearnDelFAMCode>
            </LearningDeliveryFAM>
        </LearningDelivery>



    </Learner>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
for item in soup.select('learner'):
    finaltag=item.select('LearningDelivery')[-1]
    new_tag = soup.new_tag("law-ru")
    new_tag.append("NULL")
    finaltag.insert_after(new_tag)
    new_tag = soup.new_tag("lad-ru")
    new_tag.append("NULL")
    finaltag.insert_after(new_tag)
    new_tag = soup.new_tag("db-ru")
    new_tag.append("NULL")
    finaltag.insert_after(new_tag)

print(soup)
```

Comment: I don't know how your xml is structured.However if you run this code and print soup you can see the tag added

Comment: Thanks dose exactly what I want it to do. Thanks for this. I just need to edit it to work with my original code. Thanks again

Comment: Can you accept that answer if it resolved your problem.